# Failed to post complex object in asp.net core api using jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

Failed to post complex object with list to  asp.net core api using jquery ajax

Here is the Models

```
public class Bus
{    
    public int BusId { get; set; }                
    public string RegistrationNo { get; set; }           
    public IEnumerable<BusSeat> BusSeats { get; set; }
}

public class BusSeat : CoreModel
{        

    public int DecNumber { get; set; }
    public int SeatId { get; set; }        
}
```

Here is the Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Save([FromForm] Bus bus)
{
    return Ok(bus);
}
```

Here is the javascript

```
var d = {
            BusId: 1,
            RegistrationNo: 'REG123',
            BusSeats: [
                {
                    DecNumber: 1,
                    SeatId:2,
                },
                {
                    DecNumber: 1,
                    SeatId: 4,
                }
            ]
        }

$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:46060/api/bus/save',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',                
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ bus: d }),                
            success: function (data) {                   
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
```

Request is successful, but i couldn't get any data. Anything i  am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `stringify`, `contentType` on ajax call, and don't need `[FromForm]` on the mvc action.

Just pass the complex object directly on the data parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:46060/api/bus/save',                
    dataType: 'json',
    data: d,                
    success: function (response) {                  
    },
    error: function (response) {
    }
});
```

As long as the complex json object matches the view models you define, the binding should 'magically' work.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Save(Bus bus)
{
    return Ok(bus);
}
```

This is off topic but you should think about how you construct your uris since you're building web api. You don't want to still use good old `RPC` style on your uri.

Think about the controller name as resource collection, and use `HttpMethod` as verb.

So I would create `BusesController` instead of `BusController` (Or use `[RoutePrefix("api/buses")]`), because I think about the resource as a collection - buses.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BusesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/buses
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult()
    {
        // Return all buses
        return OK(...);
    }

    // GET api/buses/1
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult(int id)
    {
        // Return individual bus
        return OK(...);
    }

    // POST api/buses
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(CreateBusViewModel model)
    {
        // Create a new bus and return newly created uri of the bus
        return Created(...);
    }
}
```

You can read more about [Richardson Maturity Model](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) here!

Answer (score 0):

Change the From part in the action to [FromBody] and in the ajax call for data just say

```
data: JSON.stringify(d)
```

Rather than

```
data: JSON.stringify({ bus: d })
```

Comment: I changed my answer and checked it in a local project. Everything binds correctly. Reason for that is how AspNetCore model binding works. In any case, it is different than the classic AspNet.